# javascript/jquery : extract phone numbers from string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to extract phone number from a string which can be empty or look like one of the following examples:

- "Tél. : 04 27 52 12 87 Port. : 07 67 11 06 87"
- "Tél. : 04 27 52 12 87"
- "Port. : 07 67 11 06 87"

In addition, a phone number could look like this: (0039) 234786
So the constant(s) are "Tél. :" and/or "Port. :"

The have put these numbers in two variables (cell & landline).

I've tried split and indexOf functions but I'm pretty sure that there's a better and more efficient way to do this.

Any ideas ?

Comment: [Regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) are probably what you want. I notice your question is marked with the tag `regex`. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I do have to be honest, I didn't work a lot with regular expressions. Therefore I'm not comfortable using and creating them...

Comment: perfect solution with example : https://stackoverflow.com/a/39587209/4050261

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you already ***know*** your string is a phone number, just replace all non-numeric characters to leave your phone number:

```
telInteger = parseInt(inputString.replace(/[^0-9]/g,''));
```

That way, it doesn't matter what the format is, you always get the number.

If you *don't know* your string has a phone number, and you're just searching in the wild, you can use the RegEx's in the other answers to **detect** a phone number.

Hope this helps

Comment: This doesn't take into account a possible + in front of the phone number.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a regular expression that looks for both versions of your phone number.
The two patterns are separated by a  pipe character (|).

On the left side of the pipe, it looks for **digit digit space** four times in a row, then a final **digit digit**.

On the right side of the pipe, it looks for **parenthesis**, then **four digits in a row**, then **end parenthesis**, then a **space**, then **six digits in a row**.

I tested it in [regexr.com](http://regexr.com) by copying and pasting your text and then in the top field, entering this:

```
/(((\d{2})(\s)){4}(\d){2})|(\((\d){4}\)(\s)(\d){6})/g
```

Note: [regexr.com](http://regexr.com) supplies outer slashes, so no need to include that from the above example, and defaults to a global "g" flag at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Using RegEx:

((Tél.\s:\s)(?([\d\s]+))?\s?([\d]+)?)?((Port.\s:\s)([\d\s]+))?

This should capture everything that you are trying to get.

I saw you said you don't have much experience with RegEx...me neither, but I just went through this tutorial (http://regexone.com/) this morning and I feel pretty confident using them now.  It's really not that much to learn (at least to be able to do a whole lot with)!

Just so you know, I did check this with a RegEx tool and it worked!