# How to fetch phone numbers from string using regular expression(Regex)?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want regex which finds out continues max 12 digits long number by ignoring space, plus (+), parenthesis & dash, e.g:

```
Primary contact number +91 98333332343 call me on this
My number is +91-983 333 32343
2nd number +1 (983) 333 32343, call me
Another one 983-333-32343
One more +91(983)-333-32343 that's all
121 street pin code 421 728 & number is 9833636363
```

Currently, I have a regex, which does the job of fetching contact numbers from string:

```
/* This only work for the first case not for any other
   and for last one it outputs "121" */

\\+?\\(?\\d*\\)? ?\\(?\\d+\\)?\\d*([\\s./-]?\\d{2,})+
```

So what can be done here to support all the above cases, in short ignoring special characters and length should range from 10-12.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I see that there are numbers ranging from 10 to 13 digits.

You may use

```
/(?:[-+() ]*\d){10,13}/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nZ2dO8/1).

**Details**:

- `(?:[-+() ]*\d){10,13}` - match 10 to 13 sequences of:

  - `[-+() ]*` - zero or more characters that are either `-`, `+`, `(`, `)`, or a space
  - `\d` - a digit

```js
var re = /(?:[-+() ]*\d){10,13}/gm; 
var str = 'Primary contact number +91 98333332343 call me on this\nMy number is +91-983 333 32343\n2nd number +1 (983) 333 32343, call me\nAnother one 983-333-32343\nOne more +91(983)-333-32343 that\'s all\n121 street pin code 421 728 & number is 9833636363';
var res = str.match(re).map(function(s){return s.trim();});
console.log(res);
```

Comment: @passion: Yes, it should since the task is to *extract "continues max 12 digits long number by ignoring space, plus (+), parenthesis & dash"*, not to *validate*. For validation, another regex would be necessary. If OP is more specific on the number formats to extract I could provide a more "targeted" regex, but the task is formulated in a very broad way.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer will match your criteria but I'd like to propose a more restrictive approach. It is quite specific to the number formats you provided :

- test specifically if a string IS a number `/^(\+(\d{1,2})[- ]?)?(\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})[- ]?\d{3}[- ]?\d{4,5}$/`
- test whether a string contains at least one number : `/(\+(\d{1,2})[- ]?)?(\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})[- ]?\d{3}[- ]?\d{4,5}/`

I made you a small fiddle where you can try out different regexes on any number of... well numbers : https://jsfiddle.net/u51xrcox/5/.

have fun.